# Block websites to a specific user in windows server 2016

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016

In the company I'm in, they want to block a specific user to access some websites.

They have to login in the computer so my idea was to block using group policy management, but I dont find that anywhere. Other users can access those websites.

I have been searching for something that can help me, but I dont find anything. I usually don't work with windows server (and others), so I just know the basics.

Comment: Internal websites? Or internet-websites? If internal (and on IIS or something), you can easily achieve this by using `<authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
    <deny users="blockeduser"/>
</authorization>` in your web.config, for example. For external (internet-)websites you should probably use a proxy server.

Comment: it's to block internet websites, like facebook and such

Comment: You should aim to use authenticated proxy solution for your users, most (or everything) you set via GPO can be bypassed.

Comment: and how authenticated proxy works?

Comment: That's way out of scope here, I'm afraid. What you could also do (very quick and very "dirty") is changing th users' host files to 127.0.0.1 or anything for the targeted sites...

Comment: Normally you wouldn't use Windows Server to do this. You would use your firewall. With most major firewall vendors, they offer an add-on license to the firewall that allows you to do web content filtering to either block specific web sites (like Facebook) or block content types (like all social media sites). I know from experience that SonicWall, Palo Alto, and Cisco offer this. The firewall talks to the domain controllers and/or the endpoints to verify the identity of the logged on user and control access based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but as temporary bodge you could create a .PAC file, host it on a webserver and create a GPO setting applied only to this one user?

**GPO**

```
User Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Internet Settings > Internet Explorer XX > Connections > LAN Settings > Use Automatic Configuration Script: http://yourwebserver/proxy/BlockSteve.pac
```

**.PAC file:**

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{



/* Block these */


if (shExpMatch(url,"*logmein.com"))
   { return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:8081;DIRECT"; }

if (shExpMatch(url,"*google*"))
 { return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:8081;DIRECT"; }





/* Allow everything else */


else
 return "DIRECT";
}
```

Comment: This works with other browsers like Chrome?

Comment: This will also work with Google Chrome as this uses the same proxy window as IE.  Other browsers (Firefox) will need the proxy setting within the browser set manually (or you could look at getting ADMX files for more browsers and setting this from a GPO too)